# Inferring Hidden States in Hidden Markov Models

Tags: hidden-markov-model, viterbi-algorithm

To decode an HMM, the usual approach is use the Viterbi algorithm where the probability of the most likely sequence of hidden states $z_1,..,z_n$ generating the observations $y_1,..,y_n$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
    \delta(z_n)=\max_{z_1,z_2,..,z_{n-1}}p(y_1,..,y_n,z_1,..,z_n)
\end{equation}

However this paper uses a different approach to decode the hidden states of HMM: [link to Supplementary file describing the method](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41586-022-04507-5/MediaObjects/41586_2022_4507_MOESM1_ESM.pdf)

They use the preditive distribution computing $P(y_t|y_{1:t})$ to decode the hidden states of HMM (below is the excerpt from the article describing the method):

\begin{align*}
 P(y_t|y_{1:t-1};x_{1:t},\theta)&=\sum_{k=1}^KP(y_t,z_t=k|y_{1:t-1};x_{1:t};\theta) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^KP(y_t|y_{1:t-1},z_t=k;x_{1:t},\theta) P(z_t=k|y_{1:t-1};x_{1:t},\theta) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^KP(y_t|z_t=k;x_{t},\theta)\sum_{k'=1}^KP(z_t=k,z_{t-1}=k'|y_{1:t-1};x_{1:t},\theta) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^KP(y_t|z_t=k;x_{t},\theta) \sum_{k'=1}^KP(z_t=k|y_{1:t-1},z_{t-1}=k';x_{1:t},\theta) P(z_{t-1}=k'|y_{1:t-1};x_{1:t},\theta) \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^KP(y_t|z_t=k;x_{t}\theta) \sum_{k'=1}^KP(z_t=k|z_{t-1}=k';x_{t-1},\theta) P(z_{t-1}=k'|y_{1:t-1};x_{1:t},\theta) \\
\end{align*}

> Since $z_{t-1}^{*}$ is the most probable value for $z_{t-1}$ , the >probabilities $P(z_{t-1}=z_{t-1}^{*}|y_{1:t-1};x_{1:t},\theta)=0$
> while that for $z_{t-1}^{*}$ would be unity.

> Thus:

> $P(y_t|y_{1:t-1};x_{1:t},\theta)=\sum_{k=1}^KP(y_t|z_t=k;x_{t},\theta) >P(z_t=k|z_{t-1}=z_{t-1}^{*};x_{t-1},\theta)$
> we selected the state that leads to the highest likelihood for the >correct behavior as compared with the
> ground truth as the most probable hidden state for time $t$, i.e.,

> $z_t^{*}=arg \max_k P(y_t=y_{true}|z_t=k;x_t,\theta)P(z_t=k|z_{t->1}=z_{t-1}^{*};x_t;\theta)$

What is the intuition behind this approach as I don't find much on this in the literature ? This method seems to be different to Viterbi algorithm, so would this give a different set of hidden states compared to Viterbi algorithm ?